# Firebase Web - Getting UID's from other users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use the "orderByChild" functionality provided by Firebase, but I stumbled upon a roadblock. The structure of my database is very simple, it looks a bit like this:

Root

```
Users

    ${UID}

        ID

            Name

            Birthday

            ...
```

Now, I'd like to search other user's names without knowing their UID.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

I could just download the users file completely but that does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: What's `ID` in this diagram? Can you give a JSON snippet containing a few example nodes?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ID is just an object containing data like the name, birthday etc...

Comment: Why are you nesting ID inside the uid parent node? That's creates another level down which you don't appear to need.

Comment: @Jay I agree with you, it shouldn't be located there. But I'd still need the uids to search the users. I figured out how to get this done by using Cloud Functions :)

Comment: You don't need id's to search the users - you can search by name, birthday etc and it will retrieve that node and return it in the snapshot. As I mentioned though, it's probably nested too deeply and ID could be removed as the parent and just have name, bday as direct child nodes of the UID - and you really don't need cloud functions for that either.

Comment: @Jay Hey, once again. Still agree about it being nested too deeply but your method would require me to first download the user object locally and search it after that. That's kind of a hit or miss thing. You could end up downloading 20 objects but also a thousand... Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something for sure. I haven't posted an answer because there's not enough information in the question; per the above comments can you post a snippet of your actual Firebase structure as TEXT please, no images and also describe why you are wanting to retrieve a specific user... oh and what's your platform. i.e. I want to know all users that like pizza.

Answer (score 0):

this about the question before posting it on stack overflow : you have to make a strategy to get this issue solved , I propose to you two possible solutions :

1)(**very bad solution**):

you parse the data from firebase and you put them in `[<String , anyObject>]` and you loop over this array in order to get the username that you want to get.
**

> Ps: in term of performance and usability the worst thing that you
>   could do is to invoke the database to get unuseful data, so don't use
>   this solution in production.

**

2) ***you make a strategy for this:***
look over what should be the relationship between a user and another and add new field for example friends and store on it the uids that you want to get.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this really isn't an "answer". Your first solution is what I described in my orignal post and your second solution is basically saying "go figure it out yourself". My strategy was perhaps storing user names in a different place as well, but there are always going to be people with the same names and Firebase doesn't allow duplicate keys so that can't be done either...

Comment: The answer for your question : You database conception is wrong!!

Comment: Than your "answer" is still no answer. Just a "go figure it out yourself" kinda comment with not even a push in the direction I should be searching for. I wasn't looking for someone to give me some code, just some help. This discussion is pointless, consider it closed!

Comment: go figure it out yourself !

Comment: You are repeating yourself!

Comment: a last comment: username cannot be a key . a last advice : you cannot just like that retrieve user data without knowing the UID, now you could consider this discussion closed I will not answer you again